# Using EJB with Future<?> object

Tags: java, ejb

How I can use async EJB's and asking for result with Future object ? Can anyone show me by a complete example.

Comment: You need to be much more specific. Can you post some code showing what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 7):

Before EJB 3.1,If you want to execute an asynchronous processing you had to use JMS and a MDB,In
EJB 3.1, you can use a simple session EJB with the @Asynchronous annotation on the method which must be called asynchronously.

```
@Stateless
@Remote(HelloEjbAsynchronousRemote.class)
public class HelloEjbAsynchronous implements HelloEjbAsynchronousRemote {

@Asynchronous
@Override
public Future<String> ejbAsynchronousSayHello(String name){
```

If your method has a return value, your method has to return an AsyncResult object which is an implementation of Future.

```
return new AsyncResult<String>("Hello "+name);
```

Comment: for more details  http://paddyweblog.blogspot.in/2010/04/ejb-31-asynchronous-session-beans.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.It was so useful for me.

Comment: Is it necessary to use @Asynchronous annotation on the method in interface or just in the client class I should use it?